# Get client query of a server query

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise, linq

I?m trying to get

how can I get the query but on the client context?

```
   SPWeb webRoot = scSite.OpenWeb();                

  SPListItem selectedItem = (from SPListItem item in webRoot.Lists["ContentIndex"].Items
```

I tried with:

```
SP.ListItem selectedItem = (from SP.List item in     context.Web.Lists["ContentIndex"].Items
```

but I got a error because the context object has not  the ".Item" property at the end!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

From the SP.List object, there are two methods to get items.  getItems and getItemsById.  If you don't know the Id of the item you want, you have to first create a new SP.CamlQuery object, then set the viewXml property the query object, then use the query as a parameter in the getItems method.  You have to load this collection into the context and execute the query.

Here is a good resource about dealing with list using javascript and the client object model.  It would be a little different in C#, but the concepts are pretty much the same.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg701783.aspx